# SQL Statement to join 2 tables together and insert into a new table (sqlite)

Tags: sql, sqlite

Okay so I've got two tables named cars and insurance

The car table goes something like:

1. reference_number
2. brand
3. colour

The insurance table goes something like:

1. type
2. reference_number

The insured table goes something like(is empty, to begin with):

1. brand
2. colour

The goal is to import all cars with insurance into the insured table.

So far all I could come up with is:

```
"SELECT cars.reference_number, insured.reference_number FROM INSPECTIONS  LEFT JOIN insured ON cars.reference_number = cars.reference_number ORDER BY cars.reference_number")
```

Comment: dbms name please

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin sqlite

Comment: Your SQL is confusing having "INSPECTIONS". Your third table shouldn't have just brand and color. With this table structures it is not even clear what you are trying to do. Select car.Refence_number, brand, colour, type from Car left join Insurance on Car.reference_number = Insurance,reference_number would be more meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

From your explanation ("all cars with insurance") - insured have reference_number too, right?:

```
insert into insured (reference_number, brand, colour)
SELECT reference_number, brand, colour 
FROM Cars 
where reference_number in (select reference_number from insurance) 
ORDER BY reference_number
```